# Failed to call browser.get() in chrome and firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, protractor

I used Protractor to test my angular app, upto yesterday it was working good, from today morning it was failed to call browser.get() it did shows below error.

> WARNING - chromeOnly is deprecated. Use directConnect WARNING - chromeOnly is deprecated. Use directConnect Using FirefoxDriver
>   directly... [launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver ERROR - Unable
>   to start a WebDriver session.
>
> e:\node\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\util.js:87
>             Error('Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at ' + url));
>             ^ Error: Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at http://127.0.0.1:53981/hub
>       at Error ()
>       at onResponse (e:\node\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\util.js:87:11)
>       at e:\node\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\util.js:42:21
>       at e:\node\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\http\http.js:96:5
>       at ClientRequest. (e:\node\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\index.js:145:7)
>       at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:95:17)
>       at Socket.socketErrorListener (http.js:1552:9)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
>       at net.js:441:14
>       at process.*tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
>   ==== async task ==== WebDriver.createSession()
>       at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.acquireSession* (e:\node\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:149:22)
>       at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.createSession (e:\node\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:123:30)
>       at new Driver (e:\node\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\firefox\index.js:189:36)
>       at DirectDriverProvider.getNewDriver (e:\node\node_modules\protractor\lib\driverProviders\direct.js:75:16)
>       at Runner.createBrowser (e:\node\node_modules\protractor\lib\runner.js:178:37)
>       at e:\node\node_modules\protractor\lib\runner.js:259:24
>       at _fulfilled (e:\node\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:797:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (e:\node\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:826:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (e:\node\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:759:13)
>   [launcher] Process exited with error code 1

**protractor.conf**

```
exports.config = {
allScriptsTimeout: 110000,
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
specs: [
    'E:/XAMPP/htdocs/Testing/Marketing/marketing.js',
],
capabilities: {
    "browserName": "firefox"
},
chromeOnly: true,
baseUrl: 'http://localhost/',
framework: 'jasmine',
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 3000000,
    isVerbose: true,
},
onPrepare: function () {
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
        baseDirectory: '/tmp/screenshots'
    }));
    new HtmlReporter({
        baseDirectory: '/tmp/screenshots'
        , takeScreenShotsOnlyForFailedSpecs: true
    });
},
```

Comment: Can you update your question with your conf.js file data?

Comment: Thanks @Girish Sortur, surely I will update my code.

Comment: Your error states that `chromeOnly` option is deprecated. Can you remove that tag and try to run your scripts again? Also where is your firefox driver located? Are you running your scripts on remote hub? Thanks

Comment: What firefox and protractor versions are you using?

Comment: Thanks alecxe, firefox version is 42.0, this issue was occured in not only firefox, in chrome also. chrome Version 49.0.2587.3 dev-m.